# If the proposition ¬p→v is true, then ¬p∨(p→q) ? Please check my solution.

Tags: logic

> If the proposition ¬p→v is true, then the truth value of the
>   proposition ¬p∨(p→q), where ¬ is negation, ∨ is inclusive OR and → is
>   implication, is
>
> 1. True
> 2. False
> 3. Multiple Values
> 4. Cannot be determined

---

**I try to explain**

---

Given ,¬p→v = p+v is valid
now ,  proposition ¬p∨(p→q) = ¬p+q ,

hence using rule of inference ,
= (p+v)→(¬p+q) = ¬p.¬v + ¬p + q = ¬p+q ,

so it cannot be determined.

**Edit :** Is my method correct ?

Comment: Just draw the truth table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula $¬p→v$ is True in two cases :

> either when $p$ is True (i.e. $\lnot p$ False) or when $v$ is True.

Thus, the assumption does not force a truth-value for $p$.

Consider now $¬p∨(p→q)$; we have three cases :

*(i)* $q$ True; in this case $p→q$ is True, irrespective of the truth-value of $p$, and so $¬p∨(p→q)$ is **T**.

*(ii)* $q$ False; now two subcases :

- *(ii-a)* $p$ True; in this case $p→q$ is False, and so $¬p∨(p→q)$ is **F**.
- *(ii-b)* $p$ False; in this case $¬p∨(p→q)$ is **T**.

---

*Conclusion* : you are right, cannot be determined.

*Note* : please, note that the previous explanation is nothing more than the description in words of the truth-table entered for $p,q,v$, observing that in all the six rows with **T** for the first formula, the second one has different values.

---

Regarding your solution : your transformations are correct, but what are they aimed to ?

The $v$ in $\lnot p \to v = p \lor v$ will not disappear, and thus you will not be able to reach the second formula.

But this "impossibility" (quite evident) is not easy to prove that way.

Comment: Shouldn't we say "cannot be determined", since a proposition cannot have multiple values (law of non-contradiction)?

Comment: @PragyAgarwal - maybe ... unfortunately, I'm not a native English speaker; thus, it is nt so clear to me which is the difefrence, in this context, between 3. and 4. But I definitely agree with you : if with 3 we mean "multiple values at the same time", this is not possible. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what $v$ has to do with the question. It seems that the statement is true if $\neg p$, and false if $p \land \neg q$.